# Range based for loop, using pointer to string

Tags: c++, c++11

In the new C++ standard, C++11, one can use range based for loop for processing every character of string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "this is an example";
    for (char &c:s1)
        //do any operation
        std::cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of reference `char &c:s1` how can I use a pointer to do that in range based `for` loop? I want to do something like `char *p` pointing to `s1`.

Comment: A pointer on what ? you mean `&c` ?

Comment: The loop iterates over each char. Where is there room for a char*? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: A better question is *why* you want a pointer. What would it do that a reference does not already provide? What kind of thing do you want to do in your loop? What is `//do any operation` ? Do you even need a pointer or reference? as if you just want to print the `char`s, then just loop by value. How can a `char *p` point to the `string s1`? It's really quite unclear what you're asking, or at least why you're asking it.

Comment: Smells a little like an XY problem to me.  Why is it you want the pointer?

Comment: Why pointer? We have references and pointers in C++ standard, so I am wondering why not pointer if we have references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The range-based for loop will not give you a pointer. However, you can make one:

```
for (char &c : s) {
    char *p = &c;
}
```

Or you can do it yourself with a regular loop:

```
// Note: Requires C++17, where s.data() is relaxed to a char* type.
for (char *p = s.data(), *e = p + s.size(); p != e; p++) {
}

// Pre-C++17 version.
for (char *p = &s[0], *e = p + s.size(); p != e; p++) {
}
```

Comment: Is it safe to modify string content that way? I hardly doubt

Comment: @Slava: Why would it not be safe? You can modify the character through the reference, or you can modify it through the pointer. They are the same.

Comment: We can argue about whether you can write a `'\0'` to `*e`

Comment: @Slava it used to be forbidden because `std::string::data()` returned `const char*`. In C++17 this is being relaxed to `char *`.  This answer wouldn't compile with a c++11 or c++14 conformant compiler.

Comment: @MM sure you can. A `std::string` may contain Nullbytes at arbitrary positions, as it has an explicit length field.

Comment: by the way, if I recall correctly, before c++11 std::string's were not guaranteed to be memory contiguous ...

Comment: The C++17 version is fine, but certainly the other one is UB in C++98.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Only undefined for zero-length strings, if I’m interpreting things correctly. In practice all implementations used contiguous storage and this UB was considered a defect in the standard.